# Perl DBIx::Class Truncate table

Tags: mysql, perl, dbix-class

I’m looking for a way to truncate a table with `DBIx::Class` but I ain’t able to find anything on the web except some suggestions such as delete all the rows instead of truncating the table.
Unfortunately, `TRUNCATE` being much faster, I’d wish to do it properly. For now, I think I’ll use `DBI` for truncating but it is a bit of a drawback.

Is this possible in any way ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: There is no `TRUNCATE`. You have to delete all rows.

Comment: You sure ? How sad it is :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute `SQL` directly within your DBIx::Class Model with a small helper function:

```
sub _sql_do {
  my ( $self , $sql ) = @_ ;

  return $self->storage->dbh_do(
    sub {
      my ( $storage , $dbh , $sql ) = @_ ;
      my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql ) ;
      $sth->execute() ;
    },
    $sql
  );
}
```